When I start jupyter with a script, RScript is automatically started and then an error is reported
I am using Windows 11 and installed RSoft 2020.03.
In my own Python service, there is a script to start Jupyter. The script content is as follows:
:: Determine the default configuration file path
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('%python% -c "import jupyter_core.paths as jp; print(jp.jupyter_config_dir())"') do (
    set config_dir=%%i
)
set config_file=%config_dir%\jupyter_lab_config.py

:: Check if the configuration file already exists
if exist "%config_file%" (
    echo Deleting existing configuration file: %config_file%
    del "%config_file%"
)

:: Generate Jupyter Lab configuration file and capture the output
echo Generating Jupyter Lab configuration file...
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('%python% -m jupyter lab --generate-config 2^>^&1') do (
    echo %%i
    echo %%i | find "Writing default config to:" >nul
    if !errorlevel! equ 0 (
        for /f "tokens=*" %%j in ("%%i") do (
            set "config_file=%%j"
        )
    )
)

:: Extract the actual path from the output line
set "config_file=%config_file:Writing default config to: =%"
echo Configuration file path: %config_file%

:: Trim leading and trailing spaces
for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%a in ("%config_file%") do set config_file=%%a
echo Trimmed configuration file path: %config_file%

:: Check if the configuration file was found
if "%config_file%"=="" (
    echo Failed to generate Jupyter Lab configuration file.
    exit /b 1
)

:: Modify the configuration file
if exist "%config_file%" (
    echo Modifying the configuration file...
    (for /f "usebackq delims=" %%i in ("%config_file%") do (
        set "line=%%i"
        if "%%i"=="# c.ServerApp.token = '<DEPRECATED>'" (
            echo c.ServerApp.token = ""
        ) else (
            echo !line!
        )
    )) > "%config_file%.tmp"
    move /y "%config_file%.tmp" "%config_file%"
    echo Configuration file modified successfully.
) else (
    echo Configuration file not found: %config_file%
    exit /b 1
)

:: Install the IPython kernel with the specified name
echo Installing IPython kernel...
%python% -m ipykernel install --user --name=%pname% --display-name=%pname%
if errorlevel 1 (
    echo Failed to install IPython kernel.
    exit /b 1
)
echo IPython kernel installed successfully.

When I run the script, a pop-up window of RScript will pop up and an error will be reported.

After clicking Confirm, the following prompt will appear in the console where the script is running：
[W 2024-12-24 14:42:50.684 ServerApp] Failed to fetch commands from language server spec finder `r-languageserver`:
    Command '['D:\\Synopsys\\PhotonicSolutions\\2020.03\\RSoft\\bin\\Rscript.EXE', '-e', "cat(system.file(package='languageserver'))"]' returned non-zero exit status 34.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\...\lib\site-packages\jupyter_lsp\manager.py", line 269, in _autodetect_language_servers
    if not spec_finder_from_base.is_installed(self):
  File "D:\...\lib\site-packages\jupyter_lsp\specs\utils.py", line 45, in is_installed
    check_result = check_output([cmd, *self.is_installed_args]).decode(
  File "D:\...\lib\subprocess.py", line 421, in check_output
    return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
  File "D:\...\lib\subprocess.py", line 526, in run
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['D:\\Synopsys\\PhotonicSolutions\\2020.03\\RSoft\\bin\\Rscript.EXE', '-e', "cat(system.file(package='languageserver'))"]' returned non-zero exit status 34.
[I 2024-12-24 14:42:50.737 ServerApp] Skipped non-installed server(s): bash-language-server, dockerfile-language-server-nodejs, javascript-typescript-langserver, jedi-language-server, julia-language-server, pyright, python-language-server, python-lsp-server, sql-language-server, texlab, typescript-language-server, unified-language-server, vscode-css-languageserver-bin, vscode-html-languageserver-bin, vscode-json-languageserver-bin, yaml-language-server

My environment package does not have any R language related content, which can be confirmed by adding the following output to the script:
%python% -m jupyter --paths
echo Listing installed Jupyter kernels...
%python% -m jupyter kernelspec list --json
set R
echo Listing Jupyter Lab extentions...
%python% -m jupyter labextension list
echo Listing Jupyter Servers...
%python% -m jupyter server list

I tried to delete the RSoft related content in the environment variable Path, and the error no longer appeared, but I am not sure whether this change has any effect on the use of RSoft.
Is there any other way?
